# How to run a .bat file from a no name folder

Tags: batch-file

I used this path to paste my script.bat : `C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder` , now i used NumLock(alt+255)to delete the folder letters(new folder)make it invisible,now my new path is:`C:\Users\user\Desktop\` and when i try to run my ''script.bat'' Of course not finds it, any solution?thank you

Comment: There are better ways to make a folder "invisible", like marking it as system folder

Comment: So the path is now `C:\Users\user\Desktop\<Alt+255>`? enclose it in quotes, then is should be found (not sure whether it depends on the current code page though)... Anyway, ever heard of the _Hidden_ attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do: cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ "